# Composer cannot find class from repository in vendor directory

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-4.3

I can't resolve problem with loading class in my symfony application.
Core of the application is in separate gitlab repository, loaded as dependency in composer.

This package is located in:

- ProjectRoot/vendor/officer/*

`composer.json` for this package is located under:

- ProjectRoot/vendor/officer/officer-domain/composer.json

`composer.json` content:

```
{
  "name": "officer/officer-domain",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"Officer\\": "src"}
  }
}
```

When trying to load `EventDispatcherInterface` from namespace `Officer\Infrastructure\EventDispatcher`:

> Attempted to load interface "EventDispatcherInterface" from namespace "Officer\Infrastructure\EventDispatcher".
>    Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Symfony\Contracts\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface" or "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface"?

`EventDispatcherInterface` is located in:

- ProjectRoot/vendor/officer/officer-domain/src/Infrastructure/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcherInterface.php

For two days, I failed to see any typos in directory structure, PhpStorm sees files correctly and hints them, maybe i should define something in services yaml in my app to point Officer/ namespace, but couldn't do that.

Any help will be appreciated, cheers :)

I looked at similar questions, but did not find any answer, if someone will point me to duplicated question with problem solver i'll happily close this one :)

UPDATE:
I solved the problem. I had classes in App\ namespace that implements interfaces from Officer\ package. Symfony could not autowire that and i had to add mapping for them in services.yaml

Thanks for help everybody, cheers

Comment: Take a look at the composer generated autoload files under vendor/composer and verify the Officer namespace points to the expected directory.  What you have looks right but obviously something is amiss.  services.yaml is not applicable to this problem.

Comment: Thank You @Cerad for reply, the namespacemap found in vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php does not contain namespace of my package, I assume it was not loaded for some reason

Comment: I searched for "composer psr-4" and the two examples I looked at had a trailing slash for the value, so ... `{"Officer\\": "src/"}`. maybe that's it, would probably be too easy though.

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autload` after you made the namespace-changes to your package's `composer.json` ?

Comment: And did you use composer to install the officer package?